# Sending and Receiving on the Same COM port using COMOCOM

Tags: serial-port

I have seen several articles and videos showing how to use COM O COM Serial Port Emulator to send on one COM port and receive on another. But in my case I have to send on one ports and I also receive on the same port. Can COM O COM software do that?

I cannot find any other place to ask the question.

Comment: You just want to receive back what you sent??  Why use a serial port at all?

Comment: In production the program sends an A and gets back a value that relates to the status of the device. The A goes out on the port and the status code is received on the same port. Since I am not connected to the device during development I would like some way to test the coms.

Comment: Not a programming question. "*I cannot find any other place to ask the question.*" -- Really? You're signed up for SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks @Sawdust for your response. If you have a useful place to ask this question, please provide the link. No place else has the information I am looking for. If this is in the wrong forum, then please move it to the correct forum. I was just looking for help using a common piece of software in the development of my program.

Comment: "*If you have a useful place to ask this question ...*" -- Why haven't you tried SuperUser?

Comment: What is Superuser?

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/1046023/scottintexas

Comment: Guess I should visit more often!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm a bit weird question. What's the point in reading what you just wrote?

If you want to send and receive on the same port the only way is to phisically loop (wire up) TX and RX on the serial port and send and receive on it.

Comment: See the comment I wrote in the first place. I query the device by sending a character out the serial port (Write). The device returns a value on the same port. My program is listening to that port for incoming data and responds to Data Received.  I am not reading what I just wrote.

Comment: My thinking was sooooo messed up on this whole question. Put a giant "NEVER MIND" on it.